# convert to datetime based on condition

Tags: pandas

I want to convert my datetime object into seconds

```
0       49:36.5
1       50:13.7
2       50:35.8
3       50:37.4
4       50:39.3
        ...    
92    1:00:47.8
93    1:01:07.7
94    1:02:15.3
95    1:05:03.0
96    1:05:29.6
Name: Finish, Length: 97, dtype: object
```

the problem is that the format changes at index 92 which results in an error: ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format before .

This error is caused when I try to convert the column to seconds

```
filt_data["F"] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+filt_data["Finish"]).dt.total_seconds()
```

when I do the conversion in two steps it works but results in two different column which I don't know how to merge nor does it seem really efficient:

```
filt_data["F1"] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+filt_data["Finish"].loc[0:89]).dt.total_seconds()
filt_data["F2"] = pd.to_timedelta('0'+filt_data["Finish"].loc[90:97]).dt.total_seconds()
```

the above code does not cause any error and gets the job done but results in two different columns. Any idea how to do this?

Ideally I would like to loop through the column and based on the format i.E. "50:39.3" or "1:00:47.8" add "00:" or "0" to the object.

Comment: You should create a function that handles the datetime conversion and apply it to to the column or create a new one. The function itself should handle how to convert each case. For example with simple if clauses by record length or some regex.

Comment: The basic problem is you don't have a datetime object you have a str representation of time which is seen by pandas as an object.  as @Tsingis states create a function to convert to either a datetime object or a time object and use that to update your finish column with a real datetime object

Comment: I understand that. My idea was to adjust the string to the specific datetime format and then convert it to datetime object type. But as I wrote I don't know how to handle this problem. I'm aware that having a function would be the best option here for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data:

```
import pandas as pd

times = [
    "49:36.5",
    "50:13.7",
    "50:35.8",
    "50:37.4",
    "50:39.3",
    "1:00:47.8",
    "1:01:07.7",
    "1:02:15.3",
    "1:05:03.0",
    "1:05:29.6",
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': times})
df
```

[image]

You can write a function that you apply on each separate entry in the time column:

```
def format_time(time):
    time = time.split('.')[0]
    time = time.split(':')
    if(len(time) < 3):
        time.insert(0, "0")
    return ":".join(time)


df["formatted_time"] = df.time.apply(format_time)    
df
```

[image]

Then you could undertake two steps:

1. Convert column to datetime
2. Convert column to UNIX timestamp (number of seconds since 1970-01-01)

```
df["time_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df.formatted_time, infer_datetime_format=True)
df["time_seconds"] = (df.time_datetime - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['Finish'].str.replace('^(\d+:\d+\.\d+)', r'0:\1', regex=True))
```

Or [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['Finish'].str.count(':').map({1: '0:', 2: ''}).add(df['Finish']))
```

Output:

```
0    0 days 00:49:36.500000
1    0 days 00:50:13.700000
2    0 days 00:50:35.800000
3    0 days 00:50:37.400000
4    0 days 00:50:39.300000
92   0 days 01:00:47.800000
93   0 days 01:01:07.700000
94   0 days 01:02:15.300000
95          0 days 01:05:03
96   0 days 01:05:29.600000
Name: Finish, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: thanks this was helpful as well and fixed the problem. Can you explain the order in the replace statement?

Comment: @Hansson this is a regex to match the times without hours